# Maximum data size for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have a database table that contains 3500 elements. And when I try to display this data, I get this message :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php on line 344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an Iterator.
[This article](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html#mass-object-processing) will show you how to handle big datas.

```
$q = $this->_em->createQuery("<DQL to select the objects I want>");
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
        // do stuff with the data in the row, $row[0] is always the object
        $this->_em->detach($row[0]); // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be GC'd immediately
 }
```

This code, instead of loading all the datas in a single array, creates an iterator to prevent that big loading and this kind of error.

However, if you're just looking on how to increase the memory size of PHP take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770179/1607098)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
```

Answer (score 0):

Google for "pagination" :) Usually there is never a reason to fetch every entity at once, because (for example) who wants to wait for and read a huge list with 3500 entries on a single page? If you really need them (for example for further processing) read and process them in chunks.

btw: It's not S2s fault, that the memory is limited :)

Comment: Actually I'm using the Jquery plugin Datatables that displays a precised number of lines at once using pagination. So what memory is limited ? and how to extend it (if it's possible) ?

Comment: Jquery can't access the database itself, thus you are probably able to do such optimizations in the backend, aren't you? ;)